# What are the benefits to creating an account sync adapter in Android?

Tags: android, architecture

We're developing a custom application that uses kerberos for authentication and are wondering if we should integrate into the Account Manager framework on Android.

What are the benefits? What are the problems? Is it a hassle?

Comment: you mean `android.accounts.AccountManager` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction.